# RSpec Should Receive With Working Unreliably

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am very confused. I have the following rspec test:

```
example "With ENV Slug" do
#Sets a variable to be read by api.releases
      ENV.stub(:[]).with("REPO_SLUG").and_return('foo/bar')

      provider.api.should_receive(:releases).with('foo/bar').twice
      provider.releases
    end
```

And it fails with:

```
 expected: ("foo/bar")
              got: (nil)
```

I was feeling curious so I tried this:

```
example "With ENV Slug" do
#Sets a variable to be read by api.releases
      ENV.stub(:[]).with("REPO_SLUG").and_return('foo/bar')

      provider.api.should_receive(:releases).with(no_args).twice
      provider.releases
 end
```

And now I get the error:

```
expected: (no args)
              got: ("foo/bar")
```

What in the world? Is there anything I am doing wrong? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are you sure the assertion fails in the same line?

Comment: Yep. That is the only line of code that checks for the string and the only line I changed between tests.

Comment: Can you include the relevant sources for your api and provider objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the function was being called twice, once with "foo/bar" and again with "nil", so both of the attempts to solve the problem failed at the same function but different call.